# Concatenate String from Two Tables

Tags: sql, string-concatenation

How do I get the name from one table into the `meta_description` of another table and add it to another string?

Two Tables are as:
1. `manufacturer_id (manufacturer_id, name)`
2. `manufacturer_description (manufacturer_id, meta_description)`

Set/Update/Replace?:
meta_description with name and concatenate a string to the name eg. "Products"

Result example:

```
meta_description = "Walmart products"
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results in a tabular format.

Comment: Add sample table data for both tables and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Update with join, I added a space between the two strings but that can easily be remove if you don't need it.

```
UPDATE manufacturer_description  md
JOIN manufacturer_id mi ON md.manufacturer_id = mi.manufacturer_id
SET md.meta_description = CONCAT(md.meta_description,' ' ,mi.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update manufacturer_description d set d.manufacturer_description = d.manufacturer_description  ||
(select i.name from manufacturer_id i where i.manufacturer_id = d.manufacturer_id );
```

You can try something like this: